# Unexpected request: GET in angular jasmine testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

During controller testing I am facing **Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/initData,Expected GET /api/empData**.For as of now I have two http call in my controller.I have the below issues.

1)After giving **$httpBackend.expectGET** for both the test cases are passing otherwise I am getting the above error.Here I want to test for one http call

2)In **afterEach** block again I have to do a **$httpBackend.expectGET** otherwise the same error it is throwing.

Below is my code snippet for that controller

```
  describe('Manager Controller',function(){

    var $scope,
        $rootScope,
        $injector,
        $controller,
        $httpBackend,
        mockManagerData,
        managerController;

    beforeEach(module('APP'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$injector_,_$controller_,_$httpBackend_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $injector = _$injector_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        mockManagerData = {
          "manager": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Sam",
              "department": "IT",
              "employee": [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Mak",
                  "profile": "developer"
                },
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "John",
                  "profile": "QA"
                },
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Tom",
                  "profile": "Dba"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
        managerController = $controller('managerCtrl',{
            $scope:$scope
        });
    }));

    it('should get manager details',function(){
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/initData').respond(200,'');
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/empData').respond(200,mockManagerData);
        $scope.getManagerDetails();//click event in controller
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/initData').respond(200,'');
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/empData').respond(200,mockManagerData);
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

})
```

Below is my controller logic

```
(function(angular){
    'use strict'
    angular.module('APP').controller('managerCtrl',managerController);
    managerController.$inject=['$scope','$http'];
    function managerController($scope,$http){

        $scope.getManagerDetails = function(){
            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/api/empData'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    //some login        
              }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });

        }
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/initData'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                 //some logic           
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    }
})(window.angular)
```

The above code is working fine but when I remove any of the http call I am getting the above mentioned erros. Please some one help.Thanks

Comment: You might have to add the controller logic which is making the request. First, you could also add some `whenGet` as it is more flexible and then clean your unit tests by using `expectGet`.

Comment: I have updated my controller logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test only for your `api/initData` or for both requests.The second call in your controller will be always made no matter you call the clickhandler or not. You could move that expectGet to beforeEach function and change it to whenGet. Then, you can unit test only the click function in your first test.

For documentation on httpBackend and difference between whenGet and expectGet refer [this.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

Comment: In afterEach block why do I need to use $httpBackend again?Without using it I am getting error

Comment: You shouldn't need      `$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/init.json').respond(200,'');
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/emp.json').respond(200,mockManagerData);` you are making two $http calls to /api/initData and /api/emitData. Not sure whyyour controller is making /api/init.json and /api/emp.json calls.

Comment: sorry that's /api/empData and /api/initData

Comment: Now my beforeEach-$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/init.json').respond(200,'');
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/init.json');


it-$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/emp.json').respond(200,mockManagerData);
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/emp.json');

and I removed those calls from afterEach.It is working fine now

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help.I have one query.If I have suppose 10 http calls happening inside controller do I need to do $httpBaackend.flush() for all those calls

Comment: You dont have to do `$httpBackend.flush()` 10 times.. if  you are testing 10 calls in a single test case thats a mistake. All your test logic will not make any calls till you tell them. l`$httpBackend.flush()` is done when you signal all the calls which are in Q. This is because calls from asynchronous and calls from tests are synchronous as you cannot write asynchronous tests. You can fire all the requests related to what you are testing with one flush() call.